# R Redshift Error in .jfindClass

Tags: r, amazon-redshift

reading the Howto on connecting Redshift to R, and am getting an error, any ideas ?

source - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/connecting-r-with-amazon-redshift/

after the driver <- line I get this error:

> driver <- JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver", "RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.9.1009.jar", identifier.quote="`")
>   Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

Answer (score 0):

this error went away when I downloaded the used the 42-driver, not the 41-driver

download.file('http://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar','RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar')

Hopefully this will help someone..  on Windows 7

Ray